# docker update 404

Tags: apt

When i do an update, this happens:

```
Err:12 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian bionic Release                 
  404  Not Found [IP: 54.192.29.142 443]
Reading package lists... Done                                                  
E: The repository 'https://download.docker.com/linux/debian bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'stable/source/Sources' as repository 'https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic InRelease' does not seem to provide it (sources.list entry misspelt?)
```

Comment: Perhaps you can give us more information about your computer's history?  Like have you updated it before or when it was last successful.  The reason why I'm asking is because I went to the link https://download.docker.com/linux/debian and I see Debian codenames such as jessie and stretch.  I don't see Ubuntu codenames.  Can you give some information as to how your system was set to that as an update source?  Any ideas?

Comment: @karel: The error message about the repo not having a Release file seems like a subsequent error to me. A repo that doesn't exist at the given url doesn't have a Release file, either ;) See my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Even though they're quite closely related and sometimes get combined into shared repositories, Debian and Ubuntu are still distinct distributions. Therefore, at `https://download.docker.com/linux/debian` you'll find packages for Debian releases like `wheezy`, `stretch`, `jessie` and so forth. But you are looking for packages for an Ubuntu release, namely `bionic`. You can find those at `https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu`. So you need to edit your source file entry accordingly.